# Usage of sails.getDatastore().driver with a generic datastore

Tags: sails.js

I have to change and query DBs dynamically. Hence, I thought to use `sails.getDataStore().driver` to manage that.

My `config.datastores.js` is like below:

```js
module.exports.datastores = {
        default: {
            adapter: 'sails-mongo',
            ...<rest of the params>...
        },
        mysqlDB: {
            adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        },
    },
```

I can't use `sails.getDataStore('mysqlDB').driver` as the `config.datastores.js` wouldn't allow me to configure a datastore without any connection parameters. I don't want to configure these as they change dynamically.

How would I approach this scenario?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was already answered in the discussions on my open-source project: https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack/discussions/81

Quick recap, micro-services with read/write are the way to go in this case.